# Storing a value changes in the DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
    <?php
    $id = rand(10000,99999);
    $shorturl = base_convert($id,20,36);
    echo $shorturl;
    $db->query("INSERT INTO maps (id, url, user_id, locationData, userData) values ( null, '$shorturl', null, '$locationData','$userData')");
```

Using the above PHP I have been trying generate a unique shorturl which gets stored into a Database and then gets sent to javascript to tell the client side the values echoed.

In an example I tested the above code and in Javascript it console.logged `lyhc` but when I checked the Database it had the following `6c796863`

The database row is set up like `url    varchar(255)    utf8_bin`

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How do you initialize your JS variable? Show us your JS code

Comment: 6c796863 taken in hexadecimal groupings of 2 characters equates to lyhc.  6c = l, 79 = y, 68 = h, 63 = c.  It looks like you're just missing a conversion between primitive types

Comment: Why are you converting from base 20?  You probably should be converting from base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code must be taking your output in a different type.
I'm using this function to generate random strings:

```
function createRandomCode($length='30'){ 
    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789"; 
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
    $i = 0; 
    $code= ''; 
    while ($i++ < $length){ 
        $code = $code. substr($chars, rand() % 33, 1);  
    } 
    return $code; 
}
```

It might be helpful.